# Centre <li> item on click with the container set to scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have got the very nearly completed, and I just need help for the last bit.

I have a horizontal scrolling navigation, which when I click an item it brings that item into the middle of the screen (worth noting that this is for mobile screens or similiar) and gives it a class of active or something.

My problem that is that it works fine when the container div is set to `overflow: hidden`, however I would like the container to be free scroll by using `overflow-x: scroll`.

But this throw the positioning out, if you scroll across, then click on a box, you will notice that it is not centered by the amount that has been scrolled before the click.

Any help would be amazing! There is a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yt7xo6mv/) here

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollTo = 0;
    $('body').on('click', "a", function() {
        var activeItem = $('li.active');
        var selectedItem = $(this).parent()

        var activeIndex = $('li').index(activeItem);
        var selectedIndex = $('li').index(selectedItem);

        scrollTo = -selectedItem.position().left + $('.container').width() / 2 - selectedItem.width() / 2;

        $('ul').css('transform', 'translateX(' + scrollTo + 'px)');
        activeItem.removeClass('active');
        selectedItem.addClass('active');

    });
 });
```

```css
div.container {
   width: 600px;
   overflow: scroll;
}

ul {
   white-space: nowrap;
   transition: all ease 750ms;
   position: relative;
 }

 ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
 }

 ul li a {
    padding: 80px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

ul li.active {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"> <a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: How about using overflow: auto;?

Comment: @user2181397 I hadn't thought of that but it doesn't make a difference though, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have to take in account, the `scrollLeft` of the container:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollTo = 0;
    $('body').on('click', "a", function() {
      var activeItem = $('li.active');
      var selectedItem = $(this).parent()

      var activeIndex = $('li').index(activeItem);
      var selectedIndex = $('li').index(selectedItem);

      scrollTo = $('.container').scrollLeft() -selectedItem.position().left + ($('.container').width() / 2) - (selectedItem.width() / 2);
      
      $('ul').css('transform', 'translateX(' + scrollTo + 'px)');
      activeItem.removeClass('active');
      selectedItem.addClass('active');
    });
 });
```

```css
div.container {
   width: 600px;
   overflow: scroll;
}

ul {
   white-space: nowrap;
   transition: all ease 750ms;
   position: relative;
 }

 ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
 }

 ul li a {
    padding: 80px;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
 }

ul li.active {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"> <a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">6</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">7</a></li>
    <li> <a href="#">8</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```